# Angular - ngOptions model value not updating

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Getting started with Angular and am having an issue getting the model binding to work for a select option in a template.

I have the following ng-options select in a template:

```
<select ng-model="listenercount" ng-options="n for n in [] | range:0:1000" ng-change="listenersUpdate()"></select>
```

I have filter which looks like this:

```
angular.module('myapp').filter('range', function() {
    return function(input, min, max) {
        min = parseInt(min);
        max = parseInt(max);
        for (var i=min; i<max; i++) {
            input.push(i);
        }
        return input;
    };
});
```

My select shows up correctly with options 0-1000 based on my filter.

In my controller I have the following:

```
$scope.listenercount = 0;

$scope.listenersUpdate = function() {
    alert('new listener count is now:' + $scope.listenercount);
}
```

My alert message pops up every time I change the select as expected, but it always show $scope.listenercount = 0. The $scope.listenercount model binding does not seem to be update the value.

Anything obvious I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any errors in browser console?

Comment: Good question.. there are no errors in the javascript console of the browser.

Comment: Could you post entire controller code?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <script>
  angular.module('myapp', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.listenercount = 0;

$scope.listenersUpdate = function() {
    alert('new listener count is now:' + $scope.listenercount);
}

    }]);
    angular.module('myapp').filter('range', function() {
    return function(input, min, max) {
        min = parseInt(min);
        max = parseInt(max);
        for (var i=min; i<max; i++) {
            input.push(i);
        }
        return input;
    };
});
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <select ng-model="listenercount" ng-options="n for n in [] | range:0:1000" ng-change="listenersUpdate()"></select>

  <tt>debug = {{confirmed}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>counter = {{counter}}</tt><br/>
</div>
</body>
```

This is working as expected

Comment: Hmm.. When I use the {{ listenercount }} to display the selected value in  my template the page updates fine in my browser whenever I change the select value. My controller however is still showing $scope.listenercount as 0.

I changed my controller to use console.log instead of alert per another suggestion, that didn't change anything.

Comment: @John My guess is that your select and your {{ listenercount }} are inside an ng-if or an ng-repeat or any directive creating its own scope. Post a plunkr reproducing the error

Comment: I added a setInterval timer to output my $scope.listenercount to console.log and it never changes. No matter what I change the select.

Has to be something with my ng-model='x' not binding to $scope.x for some syntax reason. no??

Comment: It is indeed in an ng-repeat directive! Do how do I reference a particular ng-repeat scoped variable properly?  (reading doc now.. <g>)